# 404 not found when trying to use laravel routing sytem

Tags: php, laravel

I have this in the `routes.php`:

```php
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', function()
{
    return View::make('home');
}));

Route::get('/releases', 'ReleasesController@index');
```

In `app/controllers/ReleasesController.php`, I have this :

```php
class ReleasesController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        $releases = Releases::paginate(3);

        return View::make('Releases.list', array('releases' => $releases));    }
}
```

And finally in `app/views/Releases/list.blade.php` I have the template for rendering.

I've tried to modify the home route with `/test` instead of `/`, not working also. It seems I can only have root path (aka. `/`). Hope someone can help me.

Comment: @itachi From the path of controllers and views I'd say it's a pretty safe bet :).

Comment: @SuperMario57 Please post the entire URL you are accesing in your browser. Also do you have URL rewriting enabled for your web server?

Comment: most probably this 404 error is from apache/nginx/iis rather than from laravel.

Comment: Yes it's the 4.2. I access the following url : http://localhost/releases (note that http://localhost work, i have the home page showing up). URL rewriting is enabled, and .htaccess is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> . It seems I can only have root path (aka. /). Hope someone can help me.

Your question is a little scant on details, but it sounds like you may not have `mod_rewrite` (or its nginx equivalent) setup with your web server.  Instead of

```
http://example.com/releases
```

try the URL

```
http://example.com/index.php/releases
```

My guess is URLs in the second form work correctly.  On a webserver with the rewrite module enabled, the web server will automatically turn

```
http://example.com/releases
```

into

```
http://example.com/index.php/releases
```

behind the scenes.  Either enable rewrites on your webserver, or accept URLs with `index.php` in them.

Comment: You write, if i use http://localhost/index.php/releases everything work fine. I rechecked and mod rewrite is activated, it's strange

Comment: @SuperMario57 Are you missing your .htaccess file?  Are you sure you're looking at the right web server configuration?  Is your web server configuration to look at .htaccess files? Try setting up a simple HTML mod_rewrite rule to see if it runs.  If things work with `index.php` in the URL but not without it, then mod_rewrite is almost certainly not running for your request.

Comment: After following you, i found that htaccess was not active (AllowOverride None in the config file). I set it to AllowOverride All, now rewrite is working fine. Thanks a lot for helping me, i dont like when thing don't work fine ^^

Answer (score 0):

If using IIS as web server ,Create a file with this name web.config on public folder or where index.php is with this configuration :

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```